# What is the value of $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\log(\frac{x}{yz})$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> What is the value of
>   $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\log(\frac{x}{yz})$?
>
> (a)$0$
>
> (b)$2$
>
> (c)$4$
>
> (d)does not exist

Let us take $y=mx$ and $z=mx$ where $m$ is an arbitrary parameter,then

$\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\log(\frac{x}{yz})=\lim_{m\rightarrow 0}\log(\frac{1}{m^2})=$does not exist

Is it correct??

Comment: You might also try breaking the logarithm up: $\log(x) + \log(1/y) + \log(1/z)$

Comment: Let $x=at^2, y=t, z=t$ and let $t\to 0$ for some $a\geq0$. This would give $\lim_{t\to0}\log(a)=\log(a)$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, the limit can take any values, so it DNE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the expression is well defined for $x/yz >0$, in this case

- for $x=y=z=t$ with $t\to 0^+$

$$\log(\frac{x}{yz})=\log(\frac{1}{t})\to -\infty$$

- for $x=t^2,\,y=z=t$ with $t\to 0^+$

$$\log(\frac{x}{yz})=\log(1)\to 0$$

thus the answer is correct since

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\log(\frac{x}{yz})$$

doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you say the limit is well defined, when it doesn't exist?

Comment: @zhw. I mean that it is meaningless expression when $x/yz<0$otherwise for $x/yz>0$ it can be considered as a limit and the lmit does not exist. I prefer to distinguish the 2 concepts.